# jquery mobile custom select lose focus on select option

Tags: jquery-mobile

when I click on a long list custom select a new window with possible options is displayed, at this point I have two possible actions: close the window in which case it works fine returning to the previous window without losing focus but when I select a option this returns to the previous window losing focus.

In previous versions 1.0.1 works fine.

but in 1.4.5 it does not.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-custom-20">Long list:</label>
    <select name="select-custom-20" id="select-custom-20" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

On the official website of jquery mobile are the examples:

1.4.5 do not Working
https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/

1.0.1 Working fine!!
https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/forms/selects/custom.html

Any suggestions on how to correct this in version 1.4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put inside a `custom-select` a very long list of items, JQM will create a new page with `data-role = "dialog"`. Without page transition, the focus will be restored in time, but if You like to show a smooth page transition also for the `custom-select` dialogs, You need to increase the delay for that button focus.

You can monkey-patch JQM and check for the `dialog-page` and transition.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
    $.widget( "mobile.selectmenu", $.mobile.selectmenu, {
        _focusButton : function() {
            var self = this;
            if(self.menuType == "page" && $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition != "none") {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    self.button.focus(); 
                }, 200); // increased delay
            } else {
                setTimeout( function() {
                    self.button.focus(); 
                }, 40); // default delay
            }
        }
    });     
});
```

---

Just for the sake of completeness, please note that this issue isn't noticeable if You have set `hashListeningEnabled = false` because all links are handled internally and there won't be any `window.history` manipulation.